# Find Conversion matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have simple question in matlab.
I have the equation : A*H=b
I know A and b
I try to use this expression:

```
H=A\b;
```

but I get wrong value: example:

```
       A =

       231   481
       233   488
       241   481
       243   489
b =

    11    31
     6    20
    21    31
    18    22
```

And I get

```
H =

    1.1627    0.2713
   -0.5396   -0.0791
```

so

```
A*H

ans =

    9.0386   24.6299
    7.5868   24.6189
   20.6659   27.3434
   18.6745   27.2532
```

This is no b

Comment: You may be interested to know that there are (at least) three matlab commands to solve this: pinv(A)*b, linsolve(A,b), and of course A\b. Linsolve has many more options, for instance, H = linsolve(A,b,struct('UT', true)) gives a rather different (not least-squares) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From typing `help slash` at the command prompt:

> \   Backslash or left division.
>
> A\B is the matrix division of A into B, which is roughly the same as
>   INV(A)*B , except it is computed in a different way. If A is an N-by-N
>   matrix and B is a column vector with N components, or a matrix with
>   several such columns, then X = A\B is the solution to the equation A*X
>   = B. A warning message is printed if A is badly scaled or nearly  singular.  A\EYE(SIZE(A)) produces the inverse of A.
>
> If A is an M-by-N matrix with M < or > N and B is a column vector with M
>   components, or a matrix with several such columns, then X = A\B is the
>   solution in the least squares sense to the under- or overdetermined
>   system of equations A*X = B. The effective rank, K, of A is determined
>   from the QR decomposition with pivoting. A solution X is computed
>   which has at most K nonzero components per column. If K < N this will
>   usually not be the same solution as PINV(A)*B.  A\EYE(SIZE(A))
>   produces a generalized inverse of A.

So, the second paragraph applies to your case. In other words, there is no `H` that can satisfy `A*H = b` for your problem, but Matlab computes the best approximation to it (in a least-squares sense). So the result you get is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I was think on this but I was not sure

Answer (score -1):

```
h = b ./ A;

h = 0.0476    0.0644
    0.0258    0.0410
    0.0871    0.0644
    0.0741    0.0450

A.*h = 11    31
        6    20
       21    31
       18    22
```

Or, you could add the `.` to your division, ie `h = A .\ b`

Comment: -1: first read up on [linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) and then Matlab's [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html). Your answer only works for this particular case, and moreover, is not what the OP means.

Comment: My answer worked because A and b were the same dimension matrices.  I didn't realize this system of equations didn't have an exact solution.